# Lenovo T430 double hardrive booting

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have been encountering a problem with my Lenovo T430. I have replaced main hard drive with SSD (evo850) and installed news windows-10, while original hard drive (7200 rpm) with Ubuntu is in optical drive bay with Caddy.

Problem:

whenever I start the system, as a first choice boot-loader chooses windows (SSD). Meanwhile, second drive(HDD) is loaded as an external drive. After restarting or next time when I boot the system, HDD fails to link as if not enough power to initiate or because of some reason. This " fail and read" continues in a strict "even and odd" order as if it counts the booting number.

Any ideas?

P.S. I can boot in both systems by choosing manually or choosing as a first order

Comment: Most likely you have installed Windows and Ubuntu in different modes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit your answer

Comment: Sure: Most likely the "old" Ubuntu was installed in Legacy/CSM mode and the "new" Windows in UEFI mode. It's unrelated with the actual location of one or the other though.

Comment: Ubuntu is 16.4 Lts and both were installed with Legacy mode. Do you think should I re-install them with UEFi mode?